# How can I syncronise calculations in gsheet row. start from top to bottom

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the very nice ImportJSON() script to import some rows of data from an api.

So: In Row 1 to 5000 I paste the function;
=ImportJSON(etcetc)

**The issue:**
The api has a rate limit of 28 calls a second. I modified the script to slow it down, this works. But I have to delay the script much, much more to about 1000ms because the function is running multiple calls at the same time, randomly across the rows.
If I can just get gsheet to do 1 call per row, I can time the script and not get blocked by the api. Does such a concept exist within gsheet?

Comment: If you use Apps Script, you could populate row by row with the script, using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to get the API data, and using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to put it in the sheet. Have tried using Apps Script?

Comment: thanks. Just got started with scripts a few weeks ago. This is the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apps Script, you could populate row by row with the script, using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to get the API data, and using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to put it in the sheet.

Keep in mind Apps Script has some quotas for services too. See them here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas